# useScrollDirection Hook makes slide in button to flicker

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

It is quite simple yet annoying to go around.
While scrolling down on mobile device, nothing should be happening. But the moment you scroll upwards i am using a Custom Hook to recognise direction and then trigger transition for button to slide in.
However, as the screen is still moving, my Hook is still re-rendering and makes my button flicker. It does slide in if the scrolling stopps.
I just cant get around this to make it slide in smoothly.

Here is the Hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export const SCROLL_UP = "up"
export const SCROLL_DOWN = "down"

export const useScrollDirection = (
  initialDirection = SCROLL_DOWN,
  thresholdPixels = 20
) => {
  const [scrollDir, setScrollDir] = useState(initialDirection)

  useEffect(() => {
    const threshold = thresholdPixels || 0
    let lastScrollY = window.pageYOffset
    let ticking = false

    const updateScrollDir = () => {
      const scrollY = window.pageYOffset

      if (Math.abs(scrollY - lastScrollY) < threshold) {
        // We haven't exceeded the threshold
        ticking = false
        return
      }

      setScrollDir(scrollY > lastScrollY ? SCROLL_DOWN : SCROLL_UP)
      lastScrollY = scrollY > 0 ? scrollY : 0
      ticking = false
    }

    const onScroll = () => {
      if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateScrollDir)
        ticking = true
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
  }, [initialDirection, thresholdPixels])

  return scrollDir
}
```